# Using Andy Lutomirski's Arch Linux NVMe patch with another distro

Tags: arch-linux, compiling, elementary-os

After reading over the great Arch Linux [guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_(9360)) for the Dell XPS 13 9560, I am curious about using the patch mentioned for enabling low-power modes on NVMe SSDs. To quote the repo that contains the patch's source:

> To manually compile the Archlinux kernels from here, follow steps:
>
> (1) git clone: https://github.com/damige/linux-nvme.git
>
> (2) go into /src/[kernel you want]
>
> (3) type "makepkg" -wait until compilation completes-
>
> (4) pacman -U linux-nvme-*
>
> (5) Adjust your bootloader to boot linux-nvme

I was wondering if it would be possible to compile this for Elementary OS(Ubuntu-based). Would I need to reinstall from scratch? Any advice on implementing this in other distros would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You build the kernel manually, applying [his patchset](https://github.com/damige/linux-nvme/blob/master/src/4.8.13/PKGBUILD#L81) (PKGBUILDS are just bash scripts).

Comment: Okay so with that in mind, granted I'm compiling Kernel code, it'll only be his code which is written for Arch Linux? Or can this Kernel be used/easily re-purposed to suit another distro?

Comment: His patches and building a kernel are [distro agnostic](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernels/Traditional_compilation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, jasonwryan basically commented the answer I was looking for here. The patch is applied to a linux kernel which can be compiled and used for any distro. He linked me to a couple great articles including the same Arch Linux guide on [kernels](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernels).

When I asked this question I didn't have enough knowledge about the kernel to understand how this patch is applied but thanks to him for putting me on the right track.